# Changing navigation bar buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, cydia

Hi I am making an app in Xcode 7 in Objective-C. You know how in Cydia, when a user interacts with a web element in the `webView`, the navigation bar buttons change accordingly. I have included photos below. How might I be able to do this?

[image: About Button Gives an AlertController]

About Button Gives an `AlertController`

[image: When "Featured" is selected, the About button changes to a back home button]

When "Featured" is selected, the About button changes to a back home button

---

Comment: Do you mean pushing a new view controller onto the navigation controller?

Comment: Is that what it looks like? Honestly I don't know.

Comment: That's exactly what it looks like.

Comment: How might I do this?

Comment: Read the "View Controller Programming Guide" in the iOS docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is very basic iOS stuff. Go through this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) for detailed information.

In essence, you need to create a navigation bar based application with two view controllers. From, first view controller, calling below two lines on any user action (tap on cell or button), would present second view controller on screen with Back button shown automatically by iOS.

```
MySecondViewController *viewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

This is just a glimps of how it works. You need to go through documentation to get more knowledge. Using [Storyboard](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) is another option. Explore!

Comment: But how does another screen come into play when a selection on a WebView is selected?